# put combobox filled from database into a datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, combobox

my problem is that i have a datagridview where I add different products that come from a database, each product have 4 different prices stored in the database.
I look them from an id that I put in a textbox if the ID exists the datagrid fills with its information. everything good here the problem is that I want to gather all the 4 prices of each product in one combobox inside the datagridview. i have tried a lot but nothing works. I can only make this:

```
    '*****With this I fill a combobox*****
    Dim CBdepartamento As New ComboBox
    Dim Dt1 As DataTable
    Dim Da1 As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim Cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    'Dim dat As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    With Cmd1
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "select precioventa from productos where idproducto =" & txtcodigo.Text + " UNION select pventa1 from productos where idproducto =" & txtcodigo.Text + " UNION select pventa2 from productos where idproducto =" & txtcodigo.Text + " UNION select pventa3 from productos where idproducto =" & txtcodigo.Text + ""
        .Connection = cn
    End With
    Da1.SelectCommand = Cmd1
    Dt1 = New DataTable
    Da1.Fill(Dt1)
    With CBdepartamento
        .DataSource = Dt1
        .DisplayMember = "precioventa"
        .ValueMember = "precioventa"
    End With
    '*************************************
    '****with this I fill the datagridview with the data obtained of the database***
            Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable


        Using adaptador As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT idproducto, nombre, precioventa FROM productos WHERE idproducto =" & txtcodigo.Text, cn)
            adaptador.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        dt.Columns.Add("cantidad")
        Dim cantt As Integer = 1
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

            dr("cantidad") = cantt
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray)
        Next
        '** this "for" add the pricelist in the cbox in the column "cantidad2" with only one product is fine but if I add another, in each cbox load the four prices of the first product plus the four prices of the second one that is 8 prices in each cbox... 3 products are 12 prices in the list
        For i = 0 To Dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            cantidad2.Items.Add(Dt1.Rows(i).Item("precioventa"))
        Next
```

Please help me, its almost done I just need it to repeat each product's price in each row's combobox

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to try this example? It's very simple, I know, but you can see how use many differents items in each combo in the grid:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btTest.Click
    Dim dgvColumnText As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Dim dgvColumnCombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    dgvColumnText.Name = "Producto"
    dgvColumnText.HeaderText = "Producto"
    myGrid.Columns.Add(dgvColumnText)
    dgvColumnCombo.Name = "Precio"
    dgvColumnCombo.HeaderText = "Precio"
    myGrid.Columns.Add(dgvColumnCombo)

    myGrid.Rows.Add(10)

    For i As Integer = 0 To myGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        myGrid.Rows(i).Cells("Producto").Value = String.Format("Producto {0}", i)
        Dim c As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        c = CType(myGrid.Item(1, i), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        c.Items.Add(String.Format("Precio {0}", i))
        c.Items.Add(String.Format("Precio {0}", CStr(i * 2)))
    Next
End Sub
```

You only need to add to the form: the DataGridView control (myGrid in the code), and a button (btTest).

As you can see, if you want to populate each cell with a different values, you need use the DataGridViewComboBoxCell control.

You'll find another issue: when you click the cell to set the price, you need click twice. If you don't want do it, you must use this code:

```
Private Sub myGrid_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles myGrid.CellClick
    Dim validRow As Boolean = (e.RowIndex <> -1)
    Dim mygrid As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)

    If TypeOf (mygrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)) Is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn AndAlso validRow = True Then
        mygrid.BeginEdit(True)
        Dim c As ComboBox = CType(mygrid.EditingControl, ComboBox)
        c.DroppedDown = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thank you!! I can work with this now that you gave me the idea!